# asp.net core web api center routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I have an issue related with **asp.net core center routing**. I know we could use Attribute Routing, but I did not find anything related with center routing like asp.net web api.
Something like below:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "API Default",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
```

);

Could you share me how to achieve above function in asp.net core? If there is no built-in function, could custom routing service achieve this?
Regards,
Edward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

center routing is supported for web api, but we need to disable attribute route on web api.
Route:

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "api",
            template: "api/{controller=Values}/{action=GetAll}/{id?}");
    });
```

Web API controller:

```
    //[Route("api/[controller]")]
    //[Authorize]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public ValuesController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }
        // GET: api/values
        //[HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> GetAll()
        {
            var result = from user in _db.UserInfos
                         select user.UserName;
            return result.ToList();
            //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        // GET api/values/5
        //[HttpGet("{id}")]        
        public string GetById(int id)
        {
            var result = from user in _db.UserInfos
                         select user.UserName;
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
            //return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString(); //"value";
        }
}
```

This could be requested by `http://localhost:44888/api/values/getbyid/123`

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the routes as options to MVC middleware. Add the routes to the configure method in your startup class

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute("blog", "api/{*article}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Blog", action = "Article" });
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

}
```

Note that in ASP.NET, the controller are same for both MVC and API. Its an unified model.