# Does .NET core 2.1 web API support convention based routing?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am new to Web API and .net core, and I have a task to develop an API.

So I have created a default web API (framework: .NET Core 2.1) and tried adding the route map and i am getting an error.

guys can someone help me with routing.

**Note: Cant use attribute based routing need to handle routes based on a convention like in MVC**

My startup program:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "dummyaction" });
        });
    }
}
```

And this is the error i am getting:

> InvalidOperationException: Action 'myproject.Controllers.ValuesController.dummyaction (myproject)' does not have an attribute route. Action methods on controllers annotated with ApiControllerAttribute must be attribute routed.

Comment: Why can you not use attribute routing? Regardless, there is no convention based routing such as having a `Get`, `Post`, `Put`, `Delete`, etc. actions and having those automatically respond to those HTTP methods.

Comment: Chris Pratt so if I replace all my action methods with names like these "dummyaction" and in map route, if I give default action as "dummyaction" will I be able to perform convention-based routing

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I got it working

even after using map route I was still getting the error which talks about attribute-based routing

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Values", action = "dummyaction" });
    });
```

> So in the error can you see this line "Action methods on controllers
>   annotated with **ApiControllerAttribute** must be attribute routed."

Now in my controller, I was using this particular annotation/attribute "[ApiController]" by removing that I was able to perform convention-based routing.

also, I have updated the route as below

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
     routes.MapRoute(
            name: "api",
            template: "api/{controller=Values}/{action=gogogo}/{id?}");
 });
```

references:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#mixed-routing-attribute-routing-vs-conventional-routing
section(Mixed routing: Attribute routing vs conventional routing)

[asp.net core web api center routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294177/asp-net-core-web-api-center-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this sample

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TodoController : Controller
   {
      [HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> GetTodoItem(long id)
{
//do here
    }
}
}
```

For more information follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: I have a requirement of not to add individual routes to controllers and actions instead client wants a global route.

Note: instead of get, post, put action names i will have name like studentlist, editstudent and so on