# Routing in ASP.NET CORE Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

How to use conventional and attribute routing in asp.net core web api?

Is it possible to combine both conventional and attribute routing similar to asp.net web api ?

How to specify default route in  asp.net core web api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asp.net core web api center routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294177/asp-net-core-web-api-center-routing)

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net core web api and mvc you can specify routing

1. Startup.cs in Configure method
2. Controller

**You can specify default routing in launchSettings.json. Set controller name at launchUrl property for all the profiles**

.net core 2.2, At Startup.cs configure method,

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

.net core 3.1, At Startup.cs configure method,

```
app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

According to official Microsoft documentation, Attribute routing becomes a requirement in Asp.net core web API applications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/index?view=aspnetcore-2.1#attribute-routing-requirement

You have to define attribute routes like below.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
```

> Actions are inaccessible via conventional routes defined by UseMvc or
> UseMvcWithDefaultRoute in Startup.Configure.

Comment: Route attribute definitions only become required if you are using the `[ApiController]` attribute.